# Document exact matching

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say we have a following MongoDB-collection:

```
{id:1, data:"some_data"}
{id:2, data:"some_data"}
{id:3, data:"some_data"}
{id:4, data:"some_data"}
```

I also have an php-array with element "6" that is not in the collection

```
 $q = [1,3,6];
```

If I query the collection like this:

```
 $cursor = $db->col->find(['id' => ['$in' => $q]]);
```

I'm getting documents with id's 1 and 3

But I'd like to have an empty result because the id 6 do not exist in the collection,
how can I exact match the collection?

Can I do this with just one query?

Comment: What would you like to get if `q = [1,3]`?

Comment: of course only the documents with id's 1 and 3 but only because they are currently in the collection.

Comment: So if `q = [1,3,6]`, do you want `find` to give you back 0, 1, 2,or 3 documents?

Comment: As I already said I'd like to get an empty result because id:6 is NOT in the collection

Comment: Okay, but that is like no SQL query or Mongo query I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is unique:

```
var result = db.col.find({id:{$in:q}});
if(result.count() == q.length) {
    //handle result
} else {
    //handle empty result
}
```

Comment: But what if want to do it with PHP?
Let's say I have an php array:

    $q = [1,2,3,6];

    $cursor = $db->col->find(["id" => ['$in' => $q]]);

Will this query pull down all the data?

Comment: I recommend asking that in your question, and adding the appropriate tag. I shun PHP, personally.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this just with one mongodb query, because it does not have such functionality.

Also I don't understand why exactly do you need this, you can achieve it doing something like this:

```
$q = [1,3,6];
$res = array();
$cursor = $db->col->find(['id' => ['$in' => $q]]);
foreach($cursor as $val){
  $res[$val['id']] = $val['data'];
}

foreach($q as $val){
 if (!isset($res[$val])) $res[$val] = ''; // to show that there is nothing in the results.
}
```

P.S. I have not tried this code, so there might be errors.